# How to update image source on hover?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm trying to use Next.js `Image` component to render images on my app page. I'm having issues understanding how to select and update the main Image `src` so that I can replace it with all the responsive sizes Next.js creates for `Image` elements.

I have a list of navigation links in my app menu and I want to assign data attributes to each one so that when these links are hovered over they update the main `Image` element and display a different main image for each link hovered over.

I'm new to React and the way it works, so I'm not sure what my issues are but I have made a start with some basic concepts. I have started to console log the data I have to see what I get but now I've hit a brick wall.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';

function Header() {

  const MenuHeroImg = useRef();

  function handleMouseEnter(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-project-image-url'));
    console.log(MenuHeroImg.current);
  }

  return (
    <>
     <ul>
        <li
         onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
         data-project-image-url="/public/images/projects/image_2.png"
         className={`${navigationStyles['c-navigation-menu-link']}`}>
         <Link href="/project-link-here">Link</Link>
        </li>
        <li
         onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
         data-project-image-url="/public/images/projects/image_3.png"
         className={`${navigationStyles['c-navigation-menu-link']}`}>
         <Link href="/project-link-here_2">Link</Link>
        </li>
     <ul>
     <picture ref={MenuHeroImg}>
       <Image
        src="/public/images/projects/image_1.png"
        alt="Image"
        width={660}
        height={835}
        layout="responsive"
       />
     </picture>
    </>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Console Log:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `data-*` attributes to set the images paths, move the image source into a state variable that you can then update when each `onMouseEnter` gets triggered.

Also note that images in the `public` folder are referenced as `/images/projects/image_1.png`, without the `/public`.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';

function Header() {
    const [image, setImage] = useState('/images/projects/image_1.png');

    function handleMouseEnter(imagePath) {
        return () => {
            setImage(imagePath);
        };
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                <li
                    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter('/images/projects/image_2.png')}
                    className={`${navigationStyles['c-navigation-menu-link']}`}
                >
                    <Link href="/project-link-here">Link</Link>
                </li>
                <li
                    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter('/images/projects/image_3.png')}
                    className={`${navigationStyles['c-navigation-menu-link']}`}
                >
                    <Link href="/project-link-here_2">Link</Link>
                </li>
            <ul>
            <Image
                src={image}
                alt="Image"
                width={660}
                height={835}
                layout="responsive"
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Thanks for this but is 'imagePath' a typo in the mouseEnter function? im not seeing anything happening when I implement your suggestion. I dont see errors either

Comment: It's not a typo, that's the path you pass on each `onMouseEnter` callback functions, i.e. `onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter('/images/projects/image_2.png')`.

Comment: Yeah, ignore me, I wasn't seeing the image change because I was trying to use the same image when I hovered the link (doh!). it seems to be working great

Answer (score 0):

the src should be like this:/images/projects/image_1.png;
because nextjs look for the image in the root folder that is the public folder

Comment: Thanks! But how can I use the data attribute url and add it to the Image tag element to see it change?

Comment: you can use setState to set the url and then add it to the image src something like this: const [image , SetImage] = useState("") and add it to the src: src={image} when state changes it wil automatically rerender the image and the image will change

Comment: and in the getattribute you should send two parameters the first one the attribute you want and the second one name of it and its mostly for id and classes but for the src you can use document.getElementById( 'data-project-image-url' ).querySelector("image").src

Comment: or directly give the image an id and get its src with document.getElementById("id").src